# What's the proper way to set individual options with boost program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, configuration, boost-program-options

I want to set an individual option with the boost::program_options library. The documentation doesn't seem to cover this. The `variables_map` structure the library populates inherits a map, so adding the following to my program (seems to) work:

```
namespace boost {
    namespace program_options {
        template <typename T>
        void set_in_options(variables_map m, const std::string& option_name, const T& value) {
            m.insert(std::make_pair(option_name, variable_value(value, false)));
        }
        void set_in_options(variables_map m, const std::string& option_name) {
            m.insert(std::make_pair(option_name, variable_value(true, false)));
        }
    }
}
```

But surely the library author has some "right way" to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us what is "not right" about this (except of course definining it in `boost::program_options`)? Seems that the `variables_map` is exactly what you need and have used.

Comment: @sehe It's not right that in order to set an option I would need to construct a pair and to refer to something which should be entirely an implementation detail (the 'isdefaulted' boolean).

Comment: Ah. I think that the isdefaulted could be important, but if that was not part of documented API I see your point. +1

Comment: @sehe: Umm, you haven't actually +1 'ed me :-)

Comment: corrected. I was on mobile and it's easy to forget (because not in-frame)